# Find the indicated probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

Question: A spinner has equal regions numbered 1 through 15. What is the probability that the spinner will stop on an even number or a multiple of 3?

How do I begin to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

First ask yourself if an even integer can be a multiple of $3$.

Well the multiples of $3$ less than or equal to $15$ are
$3$, $6$, $9$, $12$, $15$, but only $6$ and $12$ are even. So there are three multiples of $3$ that are not even.

Now how many even numbers are in between $1$ and $15$?

This is an application of the inclusion-exclusion principle. We don't want to double count the common elements in the events.

Comment: There are 7 even numbers... so 7+3 = 10... 10/15 = 2/3

Comment: Right. And you know there are three multiples of 3 that are not even. So now the sum of both favorable events is 10. Probability is favorable outcomes divided by all possible outcomes.

Comment: Yes. All correct!